# Is contemporary physics interpreted in an instrumentalist way?

Tags: quantum-interpretations, epistemology

I'm a master student in theoretical physics and the reason why I choose this career is far more related to the "philosophical beauty" of physics, than to my personal ability or skills.

This, in some way, can justify my question... that I hope won't be too much off-topic.

According to what I heard from my professors and to what I read (a little), after the “assumption” of the Copenhagen interpretation, the common point of view of physicists went mainly toward the **instrumentalism** side, well summarized in the Bohr's quote:

*"There is no quantum world. There is only an abstract quantum physical description. It is wrong to think that the task of physics is to find out how nature is. Physics concerns what we can say about nature..."*

Anyway, many physicists seemed to be undecided between instrumentalism and realism (e.g. Einstein had a much more realist conception of the world).

Now, as a student in physics (and not in philosophy), when I'm studying physics I almost never think about whether I'm using a realist or an instrumentalist interpretation; nevertheless, when I’m trying to understand or explain, is much more effective to think about "real" electrons, protons, fields, etc.

The problem in modern physics is that we are dealing with things that are not directly related  to our senses, and I think that in the connection between an experiment and the tangible result something about the interpretation can maybe be lost.

My question is, since I don't know anything about the contemporary debate in epistemology (and even if I would, the official philosophical position is not the effective thought of the physicists), which are the actual feelings of physicists/professors/researchers (or whatever you are) about this?

Is it just mathematical models or there is something that we can call **real**?

I don't know if this issue will appear a bit obsolete and my question too unclear, anyway, please, enlighten me.

Comment: This question borders on metaphysical and will probably be closed. But anyway, I think the thing is that it is almost never important whether things are real or just models. In fact, I don't even know how you would ever find out is something is truly real or not.

Comment: The point is that I don't want to talk about metaphysics, but epistemology. I didn't mean to start a debate on how can we tell something is real; I just want to know what actual physicists think when they are dealing with physics.

Comment: I'm afraid that would make this a poll, and thus off-topic. You could certainly ask in the chat.

Comment: I hope the philosophical interpretation of physics in the scientific community is not something that can be committed to a poll!

Comment: The attitudes of working scientists is something that's pretty hard to probe, particularly if you want a representative sample. There's been a few interesting polls reported, though, which might make a good answer. I'll look for them if I have time.

Answer (score 0):

> *"There is no quantum world. There is only an abstract quantum physical description. It is wrong to think that the task of physics is to find out how nature is. Physics concerns what we can say about nature..."*

It is good to focus on what you can say, and to be able to tell the difference between what you say about information you gain as compared to a story about things that happen when you aren't looking.

> Now, as a student in physics (and not in philosophy), when I'm studying physics I almost never think about whether I'm using a realist or an instrumentalist interpretation;

Yes you do. The fact that getting the z component of spin first, then the x component second, and then finally getting a z component again can yield different values for the two z component when it can't if you first get the z component of spin, then the z component again and then finally get the x component. This means that getting the x component literally changed the state from one that always gives a certain particular z component into a new state, in particular, changes it into a state that doesn't always give that same particular z component.  The fact that you keep in mind that order matters means you know these interactions create states rather than revealing preexisting properties.

And if you are ignoring that, you are going to get wrong results.

> nevertheless, when I’m trying to understand or explain, is much more effective to think about "real" electrons, protons, fields, etc.

You can think about wavefunctions pretty well, since they are designed to be mathematical analogs of your knowledge of the system.

> The problem in modern physics is that we are dealing with things that are not directly related  to our senses,

That's not true. You can make macroscopically large quantum systems, the fact is that we started to use the word measurement for things that don't commute so you have only two options. Option one is to go all instrumentalist and positivist to avoid assigning any reality to pretty much anything. The other option is to stop using the word measurement and just be honest about the fact that these are interactions that change things.

And most people do a little of both rather than going completely with one option or the other.

> and I think that in the connection between an experiment and the tangible result something about the interpretation can maybe be lost.

I don't know anyone that would agree with you. An interpretation is ultimately about the tangible results. And how that is or isn't connected to some formalism.

> Is it just mathematical models or there is something that we can call **real**?

There is more than math, there is a world. But most scientists aren't concerned whether something gets the label real or not, as long as your real predictions agree with your real observations that's where the word real matters.

Comment: In «I think that in the connection between an experiment and the tangible result something about the interpretation can maybe be lost» I explained it very badly. What I meant it's exacly the fact that we're interpreting. But maybe in a non legitimate way.

Comment: And about the thing of the spin components, ok, but this doesn't tell me if I'm thinking realist or not. It's just that things work this way, whether I'm thinking about a real particle or just dealing with something I know that behave that way.

Comment: -1. Seems like you just read sentence by sentence being contrarian to each. If interpretations yielded tangible results there wouldn't be so much debate. Similarly for most of your other points. The point about QM measurement is a good one though.

Comment: @Charlie Realist interpretations describe spin interactions in a way that clearly show how the result is created through the interaction. E.g. "*The pilot wave perspective on spin*" by Travis Norton in the American Journal Physics. **82** 337 (2014); http://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.4848217 but you are creating results, not learning about the world. If you truly didn't know what state you had but had many copies you could do many experiments of many interactions and start to narrow the unknowns down. But in no way did the state have those spin results before you chose which interaction to do.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy I see little debate about interpretations, most people can easily distinguish between the making a prediction part and the storytelling part of any interpretation. And while some people prefer to misrepresent other interpretations and fight straw men, most do not and very little debate ever ever happens. Which is fine. You can use any interpretation you want at any moment, for research, teaching, computing, etcetera. As long as you don't confuse the different parts you are fine and there isn't any reason to debate. They ultimately talk about the testable parts and the formalisms.